# Can I bold description meta tag?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Can I format meta tags like this, especially `og` tag, because I want bold text inside facebook share window.

```
<meta name='description' content='<strong>WELCOME TO MY NEXT PERFORMANCE</strong>'>
<meta property='og:description' content='<strong>WELCOME TO MY NEXT PERFORMANCE</strong>'>
```

Comment: Since I have no idea how facebook share works I can only tell you that it is valid html but if it will show the text bold? I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content of the attributes of a `meta` tag is by definition just text: no tags are recognized (though character references are parsed). So the example is valid, but this is just a formality. All the rest depends on software that interprets `meta` tags. It would however be odd to treat its attributes as anything but plain text.

(AND I THINK SHOUTING IS QUITE SUFFICIENT FOR MAKING THE TEXT LOOK FOOLISH, **YOU DO NOT NEED TO BOLD IT**.)